# UItableview using swift language

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8

I am using objective c code for UITableview in xcode 6 but i want to replace my objective c code to swift language

Comment: Where is your try at Swift code? This is not a site to write code for you.

Comment: If you create a subclass of `UITableViewController` in Swift most of this code is automatically created for you. Also as @Zaph has mentioned, show us what you have tried so far and we can help you.

Comment: Maybe this would be a good opportunity to learn Swift?

Answer (score 1):

Copy and pasted from the default `UITableViewController` subclass template (File > New > File > iOS > Source > Cocoa Touch Class > set superclass to `UITableViewController`):

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
```

Create a subclass of `UITableViewController` in a Swift file and adapt the code to your needs.